# Setvbuf for file descriptor created by open in C++?

Tags: android, c++, c

Does anyone know how to set an int file descriptor buffer to no buffer and to flush immediately? I've tried to use `setvbuf` but it takes a `FILE*` not `int fd`.

Kevin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A file associated with an `int` is an operating system handle.  [`setvbuf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/setvbuf) manages buffers with a C runtime library `FILE`.

To prevent buffering, you would have to use the proper operating system specific function, which perhaps can be done when the file is [opened](http://linux.die.net/man/2/open).  For example, on Linux

```
int fd = open ("/dev/whatever", O_APPEND | O_WRONLY | O_DIRECT);
```

To flush data already written, use [`fsync()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fsync):

```
#include <unistd.h>

...
fsync(fd);
```